# Detect if a <Text> element was pressed within a <TextInput> (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

On iOS, In order to make my text selectable, I have used a `<TextInput>` with children like this:

```
const linkRef = useRef(null);

const handlePressIn = e => {
  const pressedNodeHandle = e.nativeEvent.target;
  const linkNodeHandle = findNodeHandle(linkRef.current);
  const didPressLink = String(pressedNodeHandle) === String(linkNodeHandle);
  console.log({ pressedNodeHandle, linkNodeHandle, didPressLink });
};

return (
  <TextInput onPressIn={handlePressIn} multiline editable={false}>
    [<Text style={styles.blue} ref={linkRef}>lorem</Text>, 'and ipsum and foo and bar and qux and baz']
  </TextInput>
)
```

[image]

However, even when pressing on the `<Text>` my `onPressIn` handler is not detecting the correct node was pressed. Does anyone know how to solve this?